# Filters, IE, body and fonts

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

Here's something interesting, turnsout that many people out there had this problem, but i couldn't find a solution:

Problem is related (and observed) only with IE8 and IE7:
If i add `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFEEBB', endColorstr='#FFEEBB',GradientType=0 );` to css "body" then all fonts on my page are messed up! If i remove "filter", font's are back in normal.

What's wrong?

P.S. Messed up -> Fonts look jagged, exactly like there's no cleartype!

Comment: What do you mean by `messed up`? If I recall correctly, setting a DX filter disables ClearType, maybe that's your problem?

Comment: Exactly, like there's no cleartype. Is there ANY workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks very much like a proprietary Microsoft filter. Unless you know that 99% of your website users use ie, don't use those filters. Of course, if you are using this in an ie-specific style-sheet, to complement another style-sheet for proper browsers, you can use that filter without ruining your market.

Either way, I would highly recommend not using an ie-specific filter (or anything ie-specific really). Instead you should recommend to your users subtly to change to a more compliant browser, with less security holes and privacy-concerning back doors.

Comment: Well, i will forget about body gradient background and use your advice...I just HATE that peace of....software...made only to look nice instead to WORK nice :\

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer [disables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/08/31/730887.aspx) [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartypeinfo.mspx) rendering in all elements that use a `DXTransform`.

There's a workaround described [here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_IE8_clearType_fix_when_using_filters-16676.html) that involves a relatively positioned wrapper element. It seems to be working in IE8 at least.

Answer (score 1):

I"m no expert, but it sounds like you are using something that is IE specific. If so, I could not recommend highly enough that you find another way. Gone are the days of IE being the only browser to develop for and doing so will turn away numerous people.